# How to make a Unity suggestion?

Tags: unity

I have some suggestions/ideas for Unity - mainly some behavioral suggestions to make Unity more intuitive. I'm new to bug-reporting, etc. How do I go about suggesting something so that the Unity developers see it?

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for an overarching feedback on an idea you should post on the [ayatana mailing list](https://launchpad.net/~ayatana).

If it's a specific feature requestion you can [file a bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) on Unity and mark it Wishlist.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/ It is a website specifically created to talk about ideas.  There is a 'implemented' section so developers come there too ;)

Comment: No! Brainstorm will close Unity ideas, and refer them to the existing Unity channels.

Comment: Brainstorm was shutdown