# How to ask developers to think about high resolution screens

Tags: graphics, resolution, interface, usability, scaling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a Unity suggestion?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39422/how-to-make-a-unity-suggestion)

I just got a ASUS N56VZ laptop, and it`s all good, but the screen resolution 1920x1080px. **I am not asking, [how to scale ui elements](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281941/ubuntu-resolution-with-ultrabook/485408#485408)**.
If someone is interested I have found some tricks:

- increase font size in system settings
- increase unity dock size in MyUnity or system settings in modern Ubuntu versions.
- tweak userChrome.js of FireFox to make buttons|panels|icons larger
- add DefaultZoomLevel extension to FireFox to make it zoom pages initially.

But all of it is miserable, because there are some big bugs:

- window decoration elements are way too small to pick them with mouse. I can't scale window easily and I can't position my cursor fast on the close|maximize buttons.
- Tuning lines like in sound volume dialog are hardly clickable at all.
- Unity top panel (status panel & tray) hardly can contain the bigger font, so it looks ugly, but icons are still the same.
- Sometimes I can`t read text, as it is cropped (and I cant scale some dialogs as it has fixed size)
- Chromium is not usable at all (ok, it's not Ubuntu problem, but the problem still exists)
- JAVA applications are not scalable (same as above)
- In FF I am able to get descent results in most cases, but [multiplication of system font increase and browser font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783899/why-are-all-html-form-elements-huge-with-a-system-wide-font-scale-factor-2-0) increase makes system controls (combobox, lists, drop down lists) extremely big, so I cant even control the zoom level on the page.

IMHO, we should post a bug report (but what kind of bug?) and vote for it! The problem is even deeper, but at least we should ask developers to think about it.
So my question is: how can I post a report (the right words and right place) and how can we (who already has that problem, or who want it to be solved before hardware upgrade) vote for faster solution. Any ideas?

Comment: This solves most problems: [How to adapt Ubuntu to a high-DPI resolution screen](http://askubuntu.com/a/472266) --- But back to How to ask developers: You should [search on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/+search?field.text=high%2Fresolution+scaling&field.actions.search=Search) and add the problem as "also affects ..." like I did [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1304370) for the `dwb` browser

Comment: Also there is a blueprint here already at launchpad:https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/client-1404-unity7-high-dpi